# Kendo UI Date picker format

Tags: kendo-ui, datetimepicker

Hi there I am using kendo UI datepicker format as below but I want to return date format in mm/yyyy format, please help. below code does not work.

```
<input id="datetimepicker" />
<script>
$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    format: "mmm/yyyy"
});
</script>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sampleDate").kendoDateTimePicker({
    format: "MMM/yyyy"
});
```

Check the link

http://jsfiddle.net/VINO/t0hgdnfc/